# How to set 2 different fonts for drawString in a single paintComponent override

Tags: java, swing, paintcomponent

Basically, i'm writing my own sudoku app, and for the view part (of MVC), I have a single JPanel, that overrides paintComponent and draws the sudoku cells, grids and selected cell etc. But my issue is that I need two different font sizes (e.g. one for when the user puts a note in a cell, and one for actual numbers in the cell), and somehow every time I call setFont, ALL the text that's already in any cells also change sizes..

As far as I understand, the setFont applies the font to all the text in a single component i guess ? And in my case, I just have Cell[][] table that stores the numbers and notes for each cell.

```java
class Cell {
     private Point coords;
     private boolean[] notes;
     private int number;

     // Constructor + Accessors + Getters
}
```

So in paintComponent I loop over all of the cells and draw the numbers accordingly, but any call to setFont changes all the text that's already inside my grid.

```
class SudokuPanel extends JPanel {
    private static final int SUDOKU_SIZE = 9;
    private Cell[][] cells;
    private static final Font BIG_FONT = new Font("Verdana", Font.BOLD, 50), 
            SMALL_FONT = new Font("Verdana", Font.PLAIN, 12);

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        //drawGrid(g);
        //drawSelected(g);
        drawCells(g);
    }

    private void drawCells(Graphics g) {
        for (int x=0; x<SUDOKU_SIZE; x++)
            for (int y=0; y<SUDOKU_SIZE; y++)
                drawCell(g, cells[x][y]);
    }

    private void drawCell(Graphics g, Cell cell) {
        if (cell.number == 0 && cell.hasNotes()) 
            drawNotes(g, cell);
        else if (cell.number != 0) 
            writeNumber(g, cell.number, cell);
    }

    private void drawNotes(Graphics g, Cell cell) {
        for (int i=0; I<cell.notes.length; i++) 
            if (cell.notes[i]) 
                writeNote(g, i, cell);
    }

    private void writeNote(Graphics g, int i, Cell cell) {
        setFont(SMALL_FONT);      // for small size
        writeStr(g, ""+i, cell.coords.x, cell.coords.y); // definitely wrong drawing coords but not the topic of this post
    }

    private void writeNumber(Graphics g, int i, Cell cell) {
        setFont(BIG_FONT);        // for big font size
        writeStr(g, ""+i, cell.coords.x, cell.coords.y);
    }

}
```

so basically the setFont size only takes into account the last call to setFont, so should i make my Cell POJO extends JComponent ? and have each of them draw themselves by overriding their own paintComponent methods where each of them will the set a different font size accordingly ? Like so :

```java
class Cell extends JComponent {
    private static final Font BIG_FONT = new Font("Verdana", Font.BOLD, 50), 
            SMALL_FONT = new Font("Verdana", Font.PLAIN, 12);
    //cell code

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        if (hasNotes()) {
            setFont(SMALL_FONT);
            // write notes
        } else {
            setFont(BIG_FONT);
            // write number
        }
    }

}
```

but then i have no clue how to use the cells as components and merge them with my JPanel's paintComponent..

All in all, I basically just want some cells to have the Big number for actual values written, and others to have multiple small numbers in a single cell showing the notes for this cell. Thanks for any help involved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't call the component's `setFont`, call the `Graphics`' before you draw the text.

Comment: ohhhhhh so there's 2 different setFont's ? one at the graphic level and one at the component level ? thanks i'll try right now and select your answer

Comment: Great it works exactly like i wanted ! I never thought to check if Graphics.setFont existed.. thanks a lot mate! Cheers